# Cant choose a default path in java when using ImageIcon in Java

Tags: java, image, path, rendering, imageicon

Whenever i need to load some image
i have difficulties  with its path
Like i use eclipse  and  by putting it in src folder and then using this path

```
ImageIcon = new ImageIcon ("/image.png");
```

It does not load image i need to put it somewhere  in my computer  and then copy paste its path ....Its not Actually better option as when i tend to run my code in some other computer i need to change the paths of all images in my code back again
please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create "resource" folder into your project folder than paste your image into that folder and try following

```
imageIcon ii = new imageIcon(getClass().getResource("/image.png"));
```

Or use bufferedImage like following

```
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/image.png");
```

Comment: Can you post your code so that i can try to help you

Comment: Actually it works...the image is loaded but ...i am afraid it wont work on other systems...Correct  me if i am wrong

Comment: The main problem  is this only...I want that image set and a default code so that it could run on any system wuthout any changes

Comment: It will work on other systems as well, to make sure you can create a runnable jar double click on it if image loads then it will work on other systems as well

Comment: Thanks..and dude can u suggest me some books on game programming in java..i am a beginner. ..Please....if u could  tell me sources from u learnt game programming  in java

Comment: For java I have one book in mind but it's not free and pretty old but it has some basic concepts that won't change in game programming "Killer game programming in java" by Andrew Davison but i suggest you to learn more about Java before reading that book, there are also documentations available on Internet for game frameworks like slick2d and libGDX search them on Google

Comment: I have made pong and flappy bird clone a day b4 and i m comfortable  with java basics...but i donno from where can i learn java game programming. ..where to start ..i wonder from where youtubers might have leart all...And from where u did?

Comment: If you are comfortable with java then the book i mentioned is good for kick start