# why wont my piece photo in my java chess project show up?

Tags: java, swing, chess

Can someone explain why in the image icon function my photo of a chess piece wont show up on the board when i run the the program. I added the function to the main but it wont seem to show up the image icon starts between lines 36-39.

```
package chess;



import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
public class chess extends JPanel
{
    final static int WINDOW_WIDTH=600; // Width of window
    final static int WINDOW_HEIGHT=600; // Height of window

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {



        // Create Chess board

        g.fillRect(100, 100, 400, 400); // White squares
        for(int i = 100; i <= 400; i+=100){
                for(int j = 100; j <= 400; j+=100){
                    g.clearRect(i, j, 50, 50); // Black squares

            }
        }
        for(int i = 150; i <= 450; i+=100){
            for(int j = 150; j <= 450; j+=100){
                    g.clearRect(i, j, 50, 50);

                    //Print out image on board
                    ImageIcon image;                
                    image=new ImageIcon("brook.gif");
                     g.drawImage(image.getImage(),0*66,7*44,null); 

            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Chess"); // Create Frame and give it the method named "window"

        window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT); // sets the size of the window 
        window.getContentPane().add(new chess()); // adds the chess board to the window
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);     // Sets the window in the middle of the screen by setting it null
        window.setBackground(Color.BLUE);  // Window background color set to gray
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // When the close option is clicked the program will stop running
        window.setVisible(true); // Makes the window visible
    }  
}
```

Comment: Where did you store your `brook.gif`??

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46746262/8587776) might be helpful to you

Comment: just downloaded it into a file on my laptop not sure if its reading it or not

Comment: in a file called chessimages do i need to call the file somehow?

Comment: And When i hover over "brook.gif" it says "Note: the javadoc for this element could neither be found in the attached source nor the attached javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your **Project Hierarchy** should look something like this

[image: Project Hierarchy]

Then you need to change

```
image=new ImageIcon("brook.gif");
```

to following

```
image=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/brook.gif"));
```

As a final not **Make sure you are typing the name of your `gif` as it is**.

Always remember it is **case sensitive**

### For Example

For the above Hierarchy, I have to write this

```
image=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/sphere.png"));
```

Not

```
image=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Sphere.png")); // or
image=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/SPHERE.png")); 
//The above 2 lines won't work.
```

Comment: Do I need to create a resource folder to my project hierarchy?

Comment: I recommend that you create one